# What is the format of the LinkedIn id field r_basicprofile?

Tags: linkedin-api

We make use of `Sign in with LinkedIn` for a pre-existing app. The app uses the `id` field returned as part of the user's profile, however the app has restrictions on what character values can be present in the `id`.

What are the legal characters that LinkedIn will put in the `id`?

[The description](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) for `id` says

> A unique identifying value for the member.
>
> This value is linked to your specific application.  Any attempts to use it with a different application will result in a "404 - Invalid member id" error.

Testing a small sample size, shows things like `zHjkl_t-4D`, `_IcF7_r2b1` and `-1ZM8mwCKM`, which caused an issue with the field being restricted to starting with alphanumeric characters. I'd like to know the legal values so we can access if LinkedIn signups are suitable for future applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member IDs are presented in Base64 encoded format.  Any characters that show up in the [Base64 index table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) are valid.

Comment: Thanks! It is the Base64 URL encoding right? Since it uses '_' and '-'. Regular B64 encoding (which is what that index table shows) uses '+' and '/'.